# Bitcoin Transaction Builder in Python

Tags: transactions, python, python-bitcoinlib

is there a python code that helps build raw bitcoin transactions (Legacy and Segwit)?
I have seen javascript but not in python.

Comment: Have you tried python-bitcoinlib? https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/spend-p2pkh-txout.py

Comment: hey, thanks! Peter Todd, sounds very familiar...